# Не добавляются данные в таблицу sqlite3

Tags: python, база-данных, sqlite, sqlite3

Написал такой код:

```
import sqlite3
connection = sqlite3.connect('my_db.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()

query_create_table = '''
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    age INTEGER NOT NULL,
    city TEXT NOT NULL
 
'''

cursor.execute(query_create_table)

connection.commit()

query_insert = '''
INSERT INTO Users (name, age, city)
VALUES (?, ?, ?)
'''
user_data = ('Ivan', 20, 'Moscow')

cursor.execute(query_insert, user_data)

connection.commit()

connection.close()
```

Сначала выполнил ту закомментированную часть для создания бд, потом всё остальное, чтобы добавить данные. Но ничего в таблице не меняется.

Comment: Добавьте закрывающуюся скобку:  `query_create_table = '''...)'''`

Comment: Извиняюсь, забыл её здесь написать. В коде она присутствует. Он выполняется без ошибок каких-либо, но просто данные не добавляются.

Answer (score 1):

В sql запросе Вы забыли закрывающую скобку и точку с запятой:

```
query_create_table = '''
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS Users (
    id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    name TEXT NOT NULL,
    age INTEGER NOT NULL,
    city TEXT NOT NULL
 );
'''
```

Подробнее тут: https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html